# Interpreting classifier output parameters like -K, -W, -A in KNN in weka

Tags: weka

I am looking for how to match the hyperparameter alphabets names in Weka output. I need to know this to make changes to parameters in any classifier. Also then use the same value in scikitlearn in case.[image: I am referrign to the circled points in the image]

Answer (score 0):

Check [OptionHandler.listOptions](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/OptionHandler.html#listOptions--) method:

`listOptions` method returns an enumeration of all the available options.

Comment: This based on Java, right? Also will it show which parameter in weka has same function as in scitkitlearn ?

Comment: Yes it is Java. It is just the description, you have to manually match with scitkitlearn.

Comment: Ah OK. The same way we do have good links for each classifier I believe but matching these with each other is quite time consuming.